# Custom Calendar Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to make a custom calendar like this
[Kindly check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgadc.png)

I know this is Fullcalendar Premium Features Kindly tell me how I manage and make a similar calendar for myself
If anyone has a idea about aany package just like this feature tell me and if not then how we make custom Calendar

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [laravel calender](https://github.com/acaronlex/laravel-calendar)